# Resolve in Python: AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGUSR1'

Tags: python, windows, attributeerror

I am trying to install a module (metview - https://www.ecmwf.net/sites/default/files/elibrary/2018/18662-new-python-interface-metview-first-results-and-roadmap-further-developments.pdf) and after installing 'metview' using pip install metview, I get this error that I do not understand -- > AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGUSR1'

```
import metview as mv
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-6bf5b378b3e8>", line 1, in <module>
    import metview as mv

  File "C:\Users\U321103\Anaconda3\envs\Maps2\lib\site-packages\metview\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import bindings as _bindings

  File "C:\Users\U321103\Anaconda3\envs\Maps2\lib\site-packages\metview\bindings.py", line 175, in <module>
    mi = MetviewInvoker()

  File "C:\Users\U321103\Anaconda3\envs\Maps2\lib\site-packages\metview\bindings.py", line 69, in __init__
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, self.signal_from_metview)

AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGUSR1'
```

Thank you for any help. Do I need to start or raise a SIGUSR1 signal somehow in my Windows10 environment? My internet searches end up with no conclusive ways to fix this.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The documentation
https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html
says this is a user defined signal. It is supported by unix (MacOS).